# wp-postratings: list current user's unrated posts

Tags: wpdb, plugin-wp-postratings

This is the code I use to list current user's rated posts (I use the [wp-postratings](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-postratings) plugin on my site for rating posts):

```
<?php
global $wpdb, $current_user;
$userranking = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT * FROM wp_ratings WHERE rating_userid=$current_user->ID ");
if($userranking) {
    foreach ( $userranking as $userranking ) {
    echo "<li><a class='rankedposttitle' href='" .get_permalink($userranking->rating_postid). "'>" .get_the_title($userranking->rating_postid). "</a></li>";
    }
  }
?>
```

How do I list the posts that the current user has not rated yet?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be:

1. Get an array of all of the post IDs in the database.
2. Get an array of all of the post IDs that the user has rated (as you have done in your example)
3. Remove the IDs in step 2 from step 1 - you'll then have an array of all unrated post IDs by that user.